# Is it correct to use reminisce without about in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I always see "reminisce" paired with "about." Like here:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reminisce

> Ray pauses to point out the Whisky a Go Go, on Sunset Boulevard, and
>   reminisces about the night Elvis Presley went there to see the Kinks
>   play. —David Wild, Rolling Stone, 13 May 1993

It is correct to use the word without "about?" Example:

> I reminisce her in scenes clumsily filmed by my mind.

Comment: The verb **recall** can be used in that way:  *I recall her in scenes...*

Answer (score 3):

**reminisce** does not take a direct object.

You can determine this by consulting a good dictionary and looking to see whether the verb is marked as *transitive* (accepts a direct object) or *intransitive*.

In some dictionaries it will be abbreviated `[T]` or `[I]` while in others it will be spelled out.